# Create list of objects from subselect in select with HQL

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

Is it possible to create a object hierarchy with non-entity objects and a 1:n relation from a HQL-Query?

**Note: Creating Analysis objects, when fully qualified with namespace is no problem. The only problem is the association via subselect to SubAnalysis objects.**

Classes:

```
public class Analysis
{
  public List<SubAnalysis> relatedAnalysis;
  public Long someSum;

  public Analysis(Long someSum, List<SubAnalysis> relatedAnalysis)
  {
    this.someSum = someSum;
    this.relatedAnalysis= relatedAnalysis;
  }
}
public class SubAnalysis
{
  public String info;

  public SubAnalysis(String info)
  {
    this.info = info;
  }
}
```

HQL:

```
  select new Analysis(sum(t.value),
           (select new SubAnalysis(x.info)
              from SomeTable x
             where x.t = t))
    from Table t
   where t.id = :id
group by t
```

So i basically want to be able to generate a report in objects for the entities:

Table => SomeTable, SomeTable

Like:

Analysis => SubAnalysis, SubAnalysis

The real query involves a lot more summing and joining.

Answer (score 0):

Creating the Analysis object should be possible, although I'm not sure if you'd have to use the FQCN, since Hibernate has to know the exact class to use. For the SubAnalysis objects and association, I'm not sure and the documentation doesn't explicitly tell us (or I'm just blind ;) ).

Comment: Ah, yes, creating the Analysis object works. Only the SubAnalysis association and the documentation not telling anything about that is the problem.

Comment: Yes, getting a list of SubAnalysis is no problem, but hibernate seems to not be able to find an appropriate c'tor for Analysis objects. But i have no idea what it could await besides List<SubAnalysis>, SubAnalysis[] or Object[].

Comment: I'm not sure if this can be done with HQL but the Criteria API provides `Criteria.setResultTransformer` to create an instance of Analysis. Using that plus nested criteria for the association along with the corresponding result transformers might help.

Comment: I'm having the similar problem too. Can you provide a sample please? My issue is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13768124/select-multiple-new-object-in-hql-query