# select multiple new() object in hql query

Tags: wcf, nhibernate, rest, hql, dto

I have a question about hql language. I'm trying to generate DTO's via hql syntax on my WCF REST application. I have a problem with the second query. What is wrong with it? Is there any other way to reach the same result?

This works good.

```
session.CreateQuery(@"select new EntityTypeDTO(t.ID, t.Title, assc.ID)
                            from crmEntityType t
                          left outer join t.Association as assc").List<EntityTypeDTO>();
```

This does not work.

```
session.CreateQuery(@"select new EntityTypeDTO(t.ID, t.Title, assc.ID, new CustomFieldDTO(f.ID,f.EntityType,f.FieldType,f.Name,f.Value))
                            from crmEntityType t
                          join fetch t.Fields as f
                          left outer join t.Association as assc").List<EntityTypeDTO>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, the `new Xxx(field1, field2, ...)` syntax is just a convenience way for creating those DTOs in a query. It is not a fully fledged programming language and as such it most probably won't support nested `new` calls like your `new EntityTypeDTO(..., new CustomFieldDTO(...))`.

What you could do instead is select the fields into a `Object[]` and call the constructors yourself, e.g. like this:

```
List<Object[]> result = query.getResultList();

for( Object[] line : result ) {
  //this is just an example, the order depends on the field order in the select clause
  //and you'd need some casts/conversion
  new EntityTypeDTO(line[0], line[1], line[2], new CustomFieldDTO(line[3], ...));
}
```